# Divisibility is not definable over $\mathbb{N}$ with coprimality relation

Tags: logic

I am asked to show that the divisibility relation "|" is not definable over $(\mathbb{N},\perp)$, where "$\perp$" is the coprimality relation.

I am pretty sure that I should use the following:

> Let $M$ be a structure, $F$ an automorphism of $M$ and $A \subseteq M^n$ for some $n$. If $A$ is definable over $M$ then $(a_1,...,a_n) \in A \Rightarrow (F(a_1),...,F(a_n)) \in A$.

Therefore, I should find a bijection $F: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall x,y (x \perp y \Leftrightarrow F(x) \perp F(y))$ and $\exists a,b (a \mid b \wedge F(a) \not\mid F(b))$

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: For $F$ to be an automorphism, you need it to be $\iff$ and not just $\implies$.

Comment: Simply swap $4$ and $8$.

Comment: Ok, that was **really** easy...thanks